# How to pass data from view to view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a index.cshtml page and index2.cshtml partial page in my file location of Views/Index/. I want to pass data from index.cshtml to index2.cshtml without using link, don't look in page.

### For example:

index.cshtml:

```
@{
   ViewBag.data = 1;
   @Html.Partial("index2")
}
```

index2.cshtml(partial):

```
@ViewBag.data
```

Preview of index.cshtml is : 1

Comment: How are you moving from View to View? You would need to get/post the value to the action of the second view.

Comment: Another option would be to use HTML5 localStorage to store the value on the client-side on the users browser. You can then set on index1 and access on index2.

Comment: Then there's Session and TempData (basically session) objects. Not used within the view though, usually set from Controller.

Comment: Tha data is don't get from a user. I want to comminicate between wievs with the data.

Comment: TempData["xyz"] = 1; will set a session value to use on the next request and then cleared at the end of that request.

Comment: How about letting us know what you tried yourself?

Comment: you can use session, get/post request too. Be more specific !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a partial to show index2 then your viewbag/viewdata should persist to the partial but if not you can pass the view data in the renderpartial method

```
@Html.RenderPartial("index2", Html.ViewData)
```

Comment: thanks, I am using '@Html.RenderAction("actionOfindex2", "myControllerofIndex2", new { index = 1 });'